# A RESTful approach to a magazine reader app?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I'm building a magazine reader app for a campus publication I work for.

As I see it, there will be 4 components involved in the implementation:

- A Java program into which the magazine's publishers post new stories. The program creates POJOs of the class Story and serializes them into `JSON` objects.
- A database which stores the `JSON` objects created by the first program
- A `RESTful` web service (Java) that handles PUT requests from the first program by adding the passed `JSON` object to the database, and delete requests from that program by deleting objects from the database. The service also handles GET requests from the (Android) client application by returning `JSON` objects from the database to it. It also needs to be capable of accepting POST requests from the client indicate when stories are viewed, in order to maintain a count of story views.
- An Android application that uses `Gson` to deserialize the `JSON` objects passed to it by the web service into Story objects, When the app runs, it automatically connects to the webservice and gets the latest 20 Stories, from which it creates views 
  that are displayed in a `ViewPager`.

This is the first time I've created a web service (or an application backed by one) so what I'm mainly looking for here is to confirm that my basic approach is in line with best practices. I'm developing this app largely as a self-educational exercise, so I'm very open to considering alternative ways of approaching this task.

Otherwise, I do have one specific question, which is: What type of database would be best suited for storing JSON objects, and how would I set it up to store these objects?

Comment: You could consider providing a web front end rather than a java app, no client to distribute.  This can then sit in the same container/server as the web services.  I'd personally go for a grails based solution for this, but that's just an opinion hence teh comment, not an answer.  "type of database"  Any database would do, no special requirements, just whatever is easiest, my guess would be mysql

Comment: I go on the premise that this is a learning exercise, as there are proven tools that can handle this use case much easier. As far as document databases that store JSON natively, two recommendations that come to mind are [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: @vickirk: Thanks! A web front end is an excellent idea, since there will be multiple writers posting and it would enable them to post from anywhere. In terms of the database: How do I actually store the JSON objects in a table? What datatype do I select for the column? (I know this is a silly question, but I'm new to databases as well)

Comment: @Perception: Yes, this is a learning excercise, but could you refer me to the tools you're speaking about so that I can analyze their approaches?

Comment: @drewmore4  "What datatype do I select for the column"  I'd recommend not storing data in the form it happens to be passed about in, map the json field to columns and use jpa/hibernate to map pojos to the database in teh same way you map them to json.  Or if you use grails, then GORM will take care of that.

Comment: @drewmore4 - take a look at [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). Its a framework built from the ground up, on Python, by people with pretty much the same exact use case as yours (news room). A rough counterpart to Django on the Java side is [Play!](http://www.playframework.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not have them do blog posts and establish an RSS feed? Then you can use the
sample app for
[Running in a Background Service](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) as a starting point for an RSS reader. It does RSS pulls for images, and puts their URIs in a content provider.